# Inserting a space after every instance of a string within a string

Tags: javascript, string, split, type-conversion, numbers

## I'm trying to separate words in a string with spaces.

For example, I'd like to convert `"twothousandninehundredfiftyeight"` to `"two thousand nine hundred fifty eight"` (So I can later convert it to 2958, but I've already figured this out)

**I've managed to get it working using an array dictionary:**

```
var dictionary = ["one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","eleven","twelve","thirteen","fourteen","fifteen","sixteen","seventeen","eighteen","nineteen","twenty","thirty","fourty","forty","fifty","sixty","seventy","eighty","ninety","hundred","thousand"];
```

**Along with these two functions:**

```
function spaceinsert(x) {
  for (i = 0; i < dictionary.length; i++) {
    if (x.includes(dictionary[i])) {
      var pos = getIndicesOf(dictionary[i], x);
      for (g = 0; g < pos.length; g++) {
            if (pos[g] != -1 && pos[g] !=0) {
                x = [x.slice(0, pos[g]), " ", x.slice(pos[g])].join('');    
            }
      }
    }
  }
  return x
}
```

**and**

```
function getIndicesOf(searchStr, str, caseSensitive) {
    var searchStrLen = searchStr.length;
    if (searchStrLen == 0) {
        return [];
    }
    var startIndex = 0, index, indices = [];
    if (!caseSensitive) {
        str = str.toLowerCase();
        searchStr = searchStr.toLowerCase();
    }
    while ((index = str.indexOf(searchStr, startIndex)) > -1) {
        indices.push(index);
        startIndex = index + searchStrLen;
    }
    return indices;
}
```

(Sorry for the messy code, I'm new to this)

**This works fine for most numbers. For example:**

`onethousandthreehundredsixtyfive`converts to `one thousand three hundred  sixty five`, but fails to work on other numbers, such as `seventhousandtwohundredtwentytwo`
it converts to `seven thousand two hundredtwent ytwo`. `sixthousandfourhundredeightyeight` converts to `six thousand four hundred eight yeight` I think this has to do with the "word" repeating itself (*TWO*hundredtwenty*TWO*) but I can't figure out a solution to this problem.

**Any ideas?**

Comment: Note, 'fourty' is a misspelling, regardless of what english dialect you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the dictionary by length, so the longest words would be handled first, to prevent "fourteen" split to "four teen", for example.

Create a RegExp by joining the dictionary words by `|`, and wrapping as group with parentheses. Use the flags `gi` (global, case insensitive). See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gHA8Zl/1) for more information about the RegExp.

Now use `String.replace()` with the patten, and replace each match, with the match + space. Trim the result to remove the space after the string.

```js
const str = "twothousandninehundredfiftyeight"

var dictionary = ["one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","eleven","twelve","thirteen","fourteen","fifteen","sixteen","seventeen","eighteen","nineteen","twenty","thirty","fourty","forty","fifty","sixty","seventy","eighty","ninety","hundred","thousand"].sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length)

const pattern = new RegExp(dictionary.join('|'), 'gi')

const result = str.replace(pattern, '$& ').trim()

console.log(result)
```

Comment: You could simply do `RegExp(dictionary.join('|'))` and `$&` in the replacement. No need for a group.

Answer (score 1):

You can do both jobs in one go. No need to separate the words with a space then convert the new string into a number. Just loop the string one word at a time and convert as you go.

For that you'll need to a `dictionary` array of objects like so:

```
var dictionary = [ { name: "one", value: 1 }, { name: "two", value: 2 }, ... ];
```

Where you'll have to put the compound numbers first, which means `fourteen`, `sixteen`, `seventeen`, `eighteen`, `nineteen`, `fourty` (which is wrong by the way), `sixty`, `seventy`, `eighty` and `ninety` should go first so that they'll have higher priority thus `sixty` will be matched as `sixty` and not as `six` which will keep `ty` which will cause errors. The final `dictionary` array is:

```
const dictionary = [ { name: "fourteen", value: 14 }, { name: "sixteen", value: 16 }, { name: "seventeen", value: 17 }, { name: "eighteen", value: 18 }, { name: "nineteen", value: 19 }, { name: "fourty", value: 40 }, { name: "sixty", value: 60 }, { name: "seventy", value: 70 }, { name: "eighty", value: 80 }, { name: "ninety", value: 90 }, { name: "one", value: 1 }, { name: "two", value: 2 }, { name: "three", value: 3 }, { name: "four", value: 4 }, { name: "five", value: 5 }, { name: "six", value: 6 }, { name: "seven", value: 7 }, { name: "eight", value: 8 }, { name: "nine", value: 9 }, { name: "ten", value: 10 }, { name: "eleven", value: 11 }, { name: "twelve", value: 12 }, { name: "thirteen", value: 13 }, { name: "fifteen", value: 15 }, { name: "twenty", value: 20 }, { name: "thirty", value: 30 }, { name: "forty", value: 40 }, { name: "fifty", value: 50 }, { name: "hundred", value: 100 }, { name: "thousand", value: 1000 } ];
```

And the code that does both jobs in one go is:

```
function convert(str) {
   let number = 0, current = 0;                                                   // the resulting number and the current accumulated number (both initialized to 0)

   while(str.length) {                                                            // while there is still text in our string
      let item = dictionary.find(item => str.indexOf(item.name) === 0);           // find the item from dictionary at the begining of the string str (here the order of items in dictionary is important, meaning it tries to match "sixty" before it tries "six")

      if(item == null) {                                                          // if no item is found
         throw "syntax error: item could not be matched at: '" + str + "'";       // throw an error
      }

      if(item.value === 100 || item.value === 1000) {                             // if the item is 100 or 1000
         current *= item.value;                                                   // multipy it by the current amount being accumulated
      } else {                                                                    // otherwise
         number += current;                                                       // add the amount accumulated to number
         current = item.value;                                                    // and start accumulating a new amount
      }

      str = str.slice(item.name.length);                                          // move to the next item by cutting the current item out
   }

   return number + current;                                                       // don't forget the last accumulated amount
}
```

**Example:**

```js
const dictionary = [ { name: "fourteen", value: 14 }, { name: "sixteen", value: 16 }, { name: "seventeen", value: 17 }, { name: "eighteen", value: 18 }, { name: "nineteen", value: 19 }, { name: "fourty", value: 40 }, { name: "sixty", value: 60 }, { name: "seventy", value: 70 }, { name: "eighty", value: 80 }, { name: "ninety", value: 90 }, { name: "one", value: 1 }, { name: "two", value: 2 }, { name: "three", value: 3 }, { name: "four", value: 4 }, { name: "five", value: 5 }, { name: "six", value: 6 }, { name: "seven", value: 7 }, { name: "eight", value: 8 }, { name: "nine", value: 9 }, { name: "ten", value: 10 }, { name: "eleven", value: 11 }, { name: "twelve", value: 12 }, { name: "thirteen", value: 13 }, { name: "fifteen", value: 15 }, { name: "twenty", value: 20 }, { name: "thirty", value: 30 }, { name: "forty", value: 40 }, { name: "fifty", value: 50 }, { name: "hundred", value: 100 }, { name: "thousand", value: 1000 } ];

function convert(str) {
   let number = 0, current = 0;

   while(str.length) {
      let item = dictionary.find(item => str.indexOf(item.name) === 0);
  
      if(item == null) {
         throw "syntax error: item could not be matched at: '" + str + "'";
      }

      if(item.value === 100 || item.value === 1000) {
         current *= item.value;
      } else {
         number += current;
         current = item.value;
      }

      str = str.slice(item.name.length);
   }

   return number + current;
}

console.log(convert("twothousandninehundredfiftyeight"));
console.log(convert("seventhousandtwohundredtwentytwo"));
console.log(convert("onethousandthreehundredsixtyfive"));
```